# multiple forms validation in 2 separate files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 files(login.html & register.html) containing 2 forms each, with different ids. I'm trying to validate the input provided by the user in all 4 forms through the following code(in a separate .js file). `sanitycheck` is a function which validates the input fields and returns true or false. This code is only accessing the first HTML file and its forms, not the second file. Can someone explain why and how to access the second file forms?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    let form = document.getElementById("rlogin");
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        return (sanitycheck(form));

    };

    let form1 = document.getElementById("clogin");
    form1.onsubmit = function() {
        return (sanitycheck(form1));
    };

    let form2 = document.getElementById("rregister");
    form2.onsubmit = function() {
        return (sanitycheck(form2));

    };

    let form3 = document.getElementById("cregister");
    form3.onsubmit = function() {
        return (sanitycheck(form3));

    };

});
```

Comment: Do you include the JavaScript in both `.html` files? Have you checked the debugging console in your browser for JavaScript errors/logs/output?

Comment: `.js` file was included in both `.html` files. Btw, just solved the problem by altering some code with the help of console debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the resolved version of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    if(document.getElementById("rlogin") != null){
        let form = document.getElementById("rlogin");
        form.onsubmit = function() {
            return (sanitycheck(form));

        };

        let form1 = document.getElementById("clogin");
        form1.onsubmit = function() {
            return (sanitycheck(form1));
        };

    }
    else{
        let form2 = document.getElementById("rregister");
        form2.onsubmit = function() {
            return (sanitycheck(form2));

        };

        let form3 = document.getElementById("cregister");
        form3.onsubmit = function() {
            return (sanitycheck(form3));

        };
    }



});
```